# Configuring the jmsConnectionFactory in server.xml for solace resource adapter doesn't work

Tags: jms, websphere-liberty, solace, open-liberty

I am trying to integrate solace with web sphere liberty 20 version using ejb2 and solace Resource adapter. I have configured MDB bean in ejb which listens to a queue. I am able to get the messages on the MDB, but while processing I need to publish the response back to a queue and this queue name is dynamic based on the messages from the upstream system. So I can not configured publisher as stateless bean in container.

Now I want to use the connection factory in publisher code which is configured in server.xml for MDB using solace resource adapter.

I have tried the following way.

in server.xml:

```
   <featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsServer-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wasJmsSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
    <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
    <feature>ejb-3.2</feature>
    <feature>ejbHome-3.2</feature>
    <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jca-1.7</feature>  
    <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
    <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>

<resourceAdapter autoStart="true" id="solace" location="sol-jms-ra-10.10.0.rar">
    <properties.solace ConnectionURL="URL" UserName="user1" Password="pwd" MessageVPN="TEST_VPN"/>
</resourceAdapter>

<jmsActivationSpec  id="JNDI/LISTENER">
    <properties.solace connectionFactoryJndiName="myCF" destination="queue" destinationType="javax.jms.Queue" />
</jmsActivationSpec >

<jmsConnectionFactory id="JNDI/J2C/CF" jndiName="JNDI/J2C/CF">
    <properties.solace ConnectionFactoryJndiName="myCF"/>
</jmsConnectionFactory>
```

and In my publisher code, doing jndi lookup as below.

```
 Context ctx = new InitialContext();
 connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/JNDI/J2C/CF");
 connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
```

but getting the below exception

```
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:comp/env/JNDI/J2C/CF
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:355)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:149)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
```

can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a binding from resource reference name `java:comp/env/JNDI/J2C/CF` to the configured jndiName, `JNDI/J2C/CF`.

One standard way to do that is with an `@Resource` annotation in your web or ejb component that wants to look it up (you could also use the value injected by the `@Resource` annotation instead of the lookup). For example,

```
@Resource(name = "java:comp/env/JNDI/J2C/CF", lookup = "JNDI/J2C/CF")
QueueConnectionFactory qcf;
```

Another approach that you can use instead to define the resource reference is to do so within your ejb-jar.xml file.  For example,

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd"
          version="2.1">
  <enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
      <ejb-name>MyMessageDrivenBean</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>org.example.MyMessageDrivenBean</ejb-class>
      <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
      <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
      <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>java:comp/env/JNDI/J2C/CF</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
        <lookup-name>JNDI/J2C/CF</lookup-name>
      </resource-ref>
    </message-driven>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

or

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd"
          version="2.1">
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>MyStatelessBean</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>org.example.MyStatelessBean</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
      <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>java:comp/env/JNDI/J2C/CF</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
        <lookup-name>JNDI/J2C/CF</lookup-name>
      </resource-ref>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Also, given that you want a QueueConnectionFactory, you need to be using the jmsQueueConnectionFactory configuration element,

```
<jmsQueueConnectionFactory id="JNDI/J2C/CF" jndiName="JNDI/J2C/CF">
    <properties.solace ConnectionFactoryJndiName="myCF"/>
</jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
```

Comment: EJB 2 is being used in code. so cant use @Resource annotation. do we need to use resource-ref tag in ejb-jar.xml. if so, how can we do that?

Comment: Yes, I added some examples of resource-ref in ejb-jar.xml to the answer